# Details of ResetPasswordAsync method of UserManager

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, reset-password

I want to know how the ResetPasswordAsync() method of .net works from the inside, I tried a lot but unable to find any articles about it, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code for ResetPasswordAsync()

```
public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> ResetPasswordAsync(TUser user, string token, string newPassword)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        }

        // Make sure the token is valid and the stamp matches
        if (!await VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, Options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider, ResetPasswordTokenPurpose, token))
        {
            return IdentityResult.Failed(ErrorDescriber.InvalidToken());
        }
        var result = await UpdatePasswordHash(user, newPassword, validatePassword: true);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return result;
        }
        return await UpdateUserAsync(user);
    }
```

If user has clicked on forgot password then you need to check if user exists then generate a token key for password reset like below

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", 
new { UserId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", 
"Please reset your password by clicking here: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
```

After that either send recovery mail like shown above or send to your own view for recovery.

**Code is taken from Microsoft GitHub Account**

Comment: Okay...So ....it means what I am really looking for are the details of UpdatePasswordHash(user, newPassword, validatePassword: true) and UpdateUserAsync(user) methods